# Merge statement in Teradata

Tags: teradata

Is it the right merge statement? If it is not correct, please advise me.

```
MERGE INTO Table1 tgt
USING Table2 src
      ON (src.ec tgt.ec
      AND src.yyyymm = tgt.yyyymm)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
UPDATE 
SET
   column3 = src.column3,
   column5 = src.column5
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
( ec, yyyymm, column1, column2, column3, column4, column5, column6)
VALUES (
src.ec, src.yyyymm, column1 = null, column2 = 0, 
src.column3, column4 = 0, src.column5, column6 = null
);
```

Comment: Error message would be helpful. What is `column1 = null` supposed to do? If you want to insert a NULL you can either omit the column in your VALUES-list or specify `NULL` without `column1 =` (same rules as traditional Insert)

Comment: I need to give the column values null and 0? How it will work then?

Comment: `VALUES (
src.ec, src.yyyymm, null, 0, 
src.column3, 0, src.column5, null
);` It's not an Update, it's a plain Insert

Comment: update and insert both

Comment: I have less number of columns in the source than the target table. Could you tell me how it will work?

Comment: It simply Inserts the value specified (NULL or 0). If the target column is omitted in the values list, it defaults to NULL (or the default value defined for this column)